# Timer1 not counting T13CKI pulses on PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip

I have a big issue on Timer1 of a PIC18F4550. Actually I have connected a 4060 IC which provide a square signal of 4Hz on RC0 input of the micro-controller (please refer to attached image).

After launching the timer, It does not count the rising edges and stays always at 0. Here is my code for configuring Timer1.

```
void initialize_timer1(){
    TMR1H = 0;
    TMR1L = 0;
   // 16-bit mode, Main system clock is derived from another source
   // 1:4 Pre-scale Value, timer1 oscillator disabled, do NOT synchronize external and internal clock
   // Timer 1 source external pin (T13CKI), stop Timer 1  
    T1CON      = 0b10100010;
    TMR1IF_bit = 0;
    TMR1IE_bit = 1;
}

void start_stop_timer1(unsigned char onOff){
    if(onOff == 1){
         TMR1ON_bit = 1;             
    }
    else {
        TMR1ON_bit = 0; 
    }
}
```

I launch timer1 is like this:

```
void main() {
    initialize_timer1();
    start_stop_timer1(unsigned char onOff);
}
```

But when I check the value of `TMR1L` and `TMR1H` I see that they stay always at `0`.

[image]

Comment: You need an infinite loop in your main, and some way to read and report the timer count.  Can you provide a *minimal functional* main instead of just your calls in main.  It would help if this code is the *same code* you are actually trying to run.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Sorry, I should've been more precise. My code is way longer, indeed I have a while(1) in my main routine. In the post I just wanted to show how I launch the timer1. But in fact, the code is more complicated than that.

Comment: I'm well aware, but these things are much easier to debug if the code you supply is executable.  In fact, very often in the process of paring it down to a minimal executable example, you find your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pin 9 of the 4060 should never be connected to the ground otherwise you would kill the clock applied to the counter:

[image]

Before tracing the software make sure that you have got the right 4Hz square signal.

Comment: The issue was indeed coming from the 4060 IC. I ave noticed that, after disconnecting the 9th pin, it is working fine. Anyway , thank you very much for your help.